# How do we select kernels in CNN? (Convolutional Neural Networks)

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Before being fed to the neural network there are kernels applied to images for feature extraction.But, how do we understand that a particular kernel will help to extract the required feature for neural network.

Comment: That's a thing which you need to obtain by conducting a number of trials over your images. If your images are smaller then a kernel size of ( 3 , 3 ) would be perfect. For bigger images the kernel size could be ( 7 ,7 ). It depends on the features of your image. If the features in your image are relatively smaller then a smaller kernel size is expected.

Comment: I think you are missing that the kernel values are actually learned, not pre-designed as in classical image processing.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no general answer to this question, no prinicipal method to determine these hyperparameters is known. A conventional approach is to look for similar problems and deep learning architectures which have already been shown to work. Than a suitable architecture can be developed by experimentation. However conventional kernel size's are 3x3, 5x5 and 7x7.

Otherwise, there are paper about this [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.02228v2.pdf) and [2](https://github.com/ducha-aiki/caffenet-benchmark), you may want to take look to see the art of choosing hyper parameters in CNN.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the image type

- if it is a sharp image you should use small kernel. Example - (3, 3)
- if it is a blur image you should use big kernel. Example - (7, 7) or (5, 5)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).